# ASP.NET Play video without having whole byte[] at the start

Tags: c#, asp.net, video

I really didn't know how exactly specify the question so sorry if it's a bit confusing. Playing video as whole is easy task. But imagine that u just have part of it and waiting for another part to be downloaded(counting on that container supports it). Is there any possible way how to start with part u have and then add rest when it's possible? Instead of waiting for having whole video? I was doing some googling and didn't found anything near this. I'll be glad even for pointing in some direction where to look.

Thank you so much, hope i didn't violated any rules and question is clear.

Comment: If you’re sending the data yourself (and not just letting the web server do it) then implement ranges header and provide the video in a format that allows streaming

Comment: I think the lack of infos _found_ results from a lack of appropriate search terms. What you want is "Video **Streaming**". It is possible with various formats and containers. For Protocols, you'll probably want to use RTP/RTSP.

Comment: I'm receiving video divided into multiple parts in mp4 container over slow connection. I can't do nothing about this part. And one solution is to wait, put it together and i play it from disk... But i was looking for some different solution. So i was asking u guys for some suggestion.